# useEffect keeps re-rendering my components, although the object is not changing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io

I am making an application that uses socket.io. My backend is constantly sending data to my front-end and the data is rarely changing, but I need it to be realtime, so it is being sent every half a second to the front end, so the socket events get triggered every half a second and data is being set to my state variable every 0.5 seconds. However, that data as I said is rarely changing. Since there is no change in the data, I am expecting React to not re-render everything, but it is!

```
function App() {
  const [regData, setRegData] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("Data", (RegData) => {
      setRegData(RegData);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <ABunchOfComponentsRelyingOnRegData>{regData[" 1"].Val}</.....>
    </>
  );
```

So I have two issues with this code:

1. As I already described, all the components get re-rendered every time the socket event is triggered, the data being received is the same every time.
2. Initially, `regData` is undefined, so if I use it the way I used it in the code above I get an error saying that it can't access [" 1"] of undefined. If I do `{regData ? regData[" 1"].Val : null}` instead, it works, but that seems inefficient as I can have hundreds of components that depend on different data from that object, using a ternary operator in XXX components just to avoid rendering these first few runs with no data seems like a bad solution.

Solved:

I solved the issue by implementing useRef() and comparing the data and only updating the state when new data is received. Otherwise the whole component (which is basically a component that holds my whole app) was being re-rendered (no actual rerendering on user side, because nothing is changed, but still).

Tracking if initial data is received is needed, because otherwise a state will never be set.

Comparing with JSON.Stringify is sufficient in my case as the data that I am sending is a simple JS object, with just strings/integers.

Seems like too many workarounds to me, but its nothing complex and it works as expected.

I got the idea about comparing the objects and only then rendering from the answers bellow, but none of the answers was sufficient to solve the issue.

```
const [regData, setRegData] = useState();
const prevRegData = useRef();
let initialDataReceived = false;

useEffect(() => {
  socket.on("DATA", (RegData) => {
    if (!initialDataReceived) {
      setRegData(RegData);
      initialDataReceived = true;
    }

    if (!(JSON.stringify(prevRegData.current) === JSON.stringify(RegData))) {
      setRegData(RegData);
    }
  });
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  prevRegData.current = regData;
}, [regData]);

if (!regData) return <div>Loading...</div>;

return (
  <>
    <TheRestOfTheApp>..A bunch of nested components that use various data from regData..</TheRestOfTheApp>
  </>
)
```

}

Comment: That's normal behaviour of useEffect, it executes after render. You can use null-coalescing operator like regData[" 1"]?.Val if you use more recent version of ES (I think it was introduced in ES2020). What dictates re-renders is the listener in your case, not the effect, it's async code, so I think you should do your equality comparisson in the callback of the socket. Also are the parameters reference-equal or value-equal? That matters a lot. By default, setting the same value with useState won't trigger re-render if it's the same value for primitive types and the same reference for ref types.

Comment: Is `regData[" 1"]` fix? if the  answer is yes just keep `value` in state.and you can check if new state and old one are different then  you can  set the new state

Comment: Okay, this is my first time trying to use React in a project and I am confused, isn't that the whole thing behind React? It being able to detect what changes in the data and then only update the components that are using that data? I feel like I am missing something here.

Comment: You can simply wrap your stateless component in React.memo.

Comment: You're setting state everytime from the listener - that triggers re-renders regardless of what your useEffect deps array is. It's empty in your case, whcih means the body of the effect function will be executed just once to set the listeners, but the listener will keep executing on changes to the data, which triggers state change, which triggers re-render. ;)

Comment: Hi @Darkbound pls share your solution or choose an answer so others can learn from your doubt

Comment: @Jhonatan done. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Since you are calling `setRegData` inside the socket event listener, the component state gets updated and hence the re-render. If you do not wish that to happen on every "data" event, try removing the event listener after it's first emitted. Something like:

```
...
const updateData = (data) => {
  setRegData(data);
  socket.off("Data", updateData);
}

useEffect(() => {
  socket.on("Data", updateData);
}, [])
...
```

2. You can initialize `regData` to be an empty array as:

```
...
const [regData, setRegData] = useState([]);
...
```

Comment: I tried the updateData function as you suggested and it does stop the re-rendering, but it also stops receiving the events, I need to constantly receive that data, its just that the data rarely changes, but I do need to get the changes and update the UI when it happens. As for 2. I have already tried that, it doesnt work, it gives me the error that it doesnt have the properties that I am trying to access. Cant access .Val of undefined

Comment: Depending on the type of `data` you can write a custom comparator to tell if it has changed since the last update and conditionally call `setRegData` if you detect a change. For 2, you might want to access the data after verifying it exists, since the data is initially unavailable, as per your code.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using **useEffect** that function is only run once. However, the callback you passed as the second parameter in **socket.on** is being fired every time the event "Data"(*socket.on("Data"*) is happening. Every time(0.5s) the data comes, it does a **setRegData**, which is basically a **setState** but just for the new hook state. Every time you set the state, react tries to render this new property. That's why you keep it rendering constantly.

1. For your issue, I'd recommend using this

```
useEffect(() => {
  socket.on("Data", (RegData) => {
    if (regData[1].Val !== RegData[1].Val) { // or any other difference
      setRegData(RegData);
    }
  });
}, []);
```

Note that I only do the **setRegData** if the data has changed, so that would avoid re-setting the **ReData** every time the data comes to the frontend(which avoids the re-rendering issue)

2. Remember useEffect is like a componentDidMount, which is fired after the first render. This means the first time this **{regData[" 1"].Val}** is rendered the **useEffect** hasn't been run yet, the data hasn't been saved with your **setRegData**. The best way to handle this is to check if that is undefined

   {regData && regData[" 1"].Val}

However, if you have more cases where for instance your regData is an emptyObject, you should validate more fields or add more validation logic. You can create a function validator something like this

```
const isRegDataComplete = () => regData && regData[1] && regData[1].Val && ...;
...
return (
  <>
    { 
      isRegDataComplete() && regData[1].Val} 
    }
  <>
);
```